# woocommerce_order_status_changed hook: getting old and new status?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I get the old status and new status of an order using the WooCommerce hook: `woocommerce_order_status_changed`?

This is my code, but only the `$order_id` is filled..

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','woo_order_status_change_custom');
function woo_order_status_change_custom($order_id,$old_status,$new_status) {
//order ID is filled
//old_status and new_status never
//tested by logging the parameters
}
```

Now I can easily get the new status using this code:

```
 $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$orderstatus = $order->status;
```

But how can I get the previous order status, since `$old_status` is empty?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That only shows the new status, not the old status.. Looking at the woocommerce_order_status_changed hook, I would expect that I could use the parameters old_status and new_status, but they remain empty..

Comment: Thanks, but the $old_status and $new_status are always empty..? Only the $order_id has a value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was looking for wc hooks and found this post. The reason the parameters are not set is that you're missing arguments in the add_action function. This function defaults to only one parameter. To have all three you should use:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'woo_order_status_change_custom', 10, 3);
```

The `10` is the default ordering for actions in Wordpress, and the last argument is the number of parameters that Wordpress should pass to the custom action.

Answer (score 4):

Because you didn't added NUMBER of parameters at the end of add_action call. Here is correct line:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','woo_order_status_change_custom', 10, 3);
```

"10, 3" means "I want 3 parameters will be sent to my callback function". By default there is only 1 parameter (order_id) will be sent.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. According to me it should work based on your comments.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse63478_save' );
function wpse63478_save() {

 if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
   return false;
 if(!is_admin())
    return false;
 if($_REQUEST['post_type'] != 'shop_order')
    return false;
 if($_REQUEST['post_ID']!='')
 {
    $orderId = $_REQUEST['post_ID'];
    $order = new WC_Order( $orderId );
    $currentStatus = $order->status;
    $requestedStautus = $_REQUEST['order_status'];
    if ( $requestedStautus== 'on-hold' and $currentStatus == 'completed') {
        //Do your work here
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this. Quick question in advance: the !is_admin(), does this mean it will only work when the save is executed from the WP backend? Because an order will probably get the staus 'completed' during checkout payment in most cases. I'm wondering if in that case this will pas the !is_admin() check.

Comment: is_admin means this code execute only from backend as save_post hook can be called from front-end as well. so for security reason i put that code.

Comment: let me know if it is not working for you and if it works for you give the correct answer and upvote so other can take this as a reference.

Comment: Hi, if I'd want to use this also in frontend (because when a user buys a virtual product and pays directly on checkout, the order status will change to completed directly): in this case, would it be safe to remove the user_can and is_admin() checks, since the current user would be a guest checking out?

Comment: yes remove it so all user can update the post but with that you need to submit the post id and postype in hidden fields.